# "<" в пароле <connectionStrings> C#

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет ребята.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Server=RDA-1; User ID=sa; Password=XNj<kz; Database = TestBase;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Пароль=XNj<kz Содержит символ **"<"** и C# говорит что нужно зактыть тег. Но Я его и не открывал. Как правильно написать пароль в данной разметке?

Comment: Хороший вопрос... Что-то мне кажется, что замена `<` на `&lt;` в данном месте не прокатит и придётся менять пароль.

Comment: @AK думаю, прокатит. Это ведь xml и здесь connectionString - это атрибут, а справа от него - значение атрибута

Comment: Теперь говорить что объект не оопределен

Comment: @НикитаВасильев попробуйте другой формат connectionString: `connectionString="Data Source=RDA-1;Initial Catalog=TestBase;User ID=sa;Password=XNj&lt;kz"`

Comment: Странно, что "не определён", ведь да, на английском куча тем гуглится, что помогает: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26392176/5752652 https://stackoverflow.com/q/61486081/5752652 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/5752652 Покажите на что заменили.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Server=trnh-db-01; User ID=sa; Password=Zlh`&ltyfnjy; Database = TestBase;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: &lt; нужно так писать

Comment: Я сначала подумал символ ";" не нужен а он как раз является частью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ
`&lt;` нужно так писать